# How to fix it the setting of date values in a railway postgresql database?

Tags: database, cloud, railway

I am a brazilian programmer, i create a postgresql instance in railway.app to use as database to a site, but when i manually or through the site i set a date value in at least one table the value date that is saved is the last day (set 2023-05-30 saved 2023-05-29). Why is this happening and how to fix it?

PS: I send a e-mail to Railway yesterday and still no response.

I don't even know how to try fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried saving date with timezone? Here is an example

```
INSERT INTO my_table (event_timestamp)
VALUES ('2023-05-31 15:30:00+03');
```

Comment: I tried this, still the same problem.